# Why is my image not showing in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
      <Image 
      source={{
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      require: ('./assets/share.png')
      }}
      />
```

I have already imported Image from react-native and the picture is in the correct assets folder.

Answer (score 1):

You are putting the `width` and `height` inside `source` prop. This should be inside `style` prop.

Also there are few errors when `require` an image.

```
 <Image 
    style={{
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
    }}
    source={require('./assets/share.png')}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you Erick! I am learning :) Thanks for the edit. Have a nice day